# Change in embedded signing request: 'returnUrl' parameter must be an absolute URL

Tags: docusignapi

For the past several months I have a native iOS application that uses the embedded signing API to generate an embedded signing URL.  My parameter for `returnUrl` uses a URL with a custom scheme, say, for example, `foo`.  I was using this custom scheme to intercept when the signing is complete and transition to another part of my application.  This is now broken and get the following response:

```
{
  "errorCode": "INVALID_REQUEST_PARAMETER",
  "message": "The request contained at least one invalid parameter. 'returnUrl' parameter must be an absolute URL."
}
```

When I try using the schemes `http` or `https` the request works just fine.  For example:

`https://docusign/complete` works

`http://docusign/complete` works

`foo://docusign/complete` broken

`bar://docusign/complete` broken

This is in the dev sandbox and I am not aware of this being broken in production. Is this change intentional or a bug?  If intentional, why are you breaking the behavior of the client being able to choose their own URL for redirection?  Using this custom scheme, I am able to unequivocally determine that my application is responding to a completion event, without having to introspect any other parts of the URL.

Comment: are you using API v2.1 or v2.0?

Comment: also, are you using one of the mobile SDKs?

Comment: @InbarGazit v2.1; I am using the REST API.

Comment: see answer from Larry, we're on it

Comment: We believe the bug has been fixed. Please re-test. Thank you for the problem report.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This breaking change is a bug that was introduced by mistake. Thank you for your report on it. I'm escalating it.

This issue is now tracked internally as DocuSign IM-32736

Please contact DocuSign customer support and ask them to add your contact information to IM-32736. Thank you.

This bug has now been declared as a release blocker. It will not go to production. The bug is being fixed and tested. It will probably arrive on demo.docusign.net sometime on Friday. I will update this answer as more progress is made.

### Update

The bug has been fixed and the fix has been pushed to demo.docusign.net.

Please advise if this is still an issue. Thank you again for reporting it.